# Map function that needs to be faster

Tags: python, hadoop, optimization, mapreduce, primes

I am trying to optimize my code to run on a hadoop cluster. Can anyone help me find some ways to make this better? I am taking in a very large set of numbers 40+ million and each number is on a new line. As numbers read in I am counting each number, summing all numbers and also checking each number to see if it is a prime.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import string
import math

total_of_primes = 0
total = 0
count = 0
not_prime = 0
count_string = 'Count:'
total_string = 'Total:'
prime_string = 'Number of Primes:'

for line in sys.stdin:
  try:
    key = int(line)
  except:
    continue
  total = total + key
  count = count + 1
  if key == 2 or key == 3:
    not_prime = not_prime - 1
  elif key%2 == 0 or key%3 == 0:
    not_prime = not_prime + 1
  else:  
    for i in range(5,(int(math.sqrt(key))+1),6):
      if key%i == 0 or key%(i+2) ==0:
        not_prime = not_prime + 1
        break

total_of_primes = count - not_prime  


print '%s\t%s' % (count_string,count)
print '%s\t%s' % (total_string,total)
print '%s\t%s' % (prime_string,total_of_primes)
```

Comment: Why would you *reduce* the count of composite numbers when you see a 2 or 3?

Comment: 2 and 3 are both prime numbers, however 1 is not.

Comment: Yeah, but if the input is just the two numbers 2 and 3, have you seen negative two composite numbers?

Comment: True, I changed it. Created a variable that keeps track of primes and just add to that if 2 and 3 are read in.

Comment: What's the largest number than can be read in?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to take everything and turn it into a comprehension. Comprehensions are faster than native Python code, because they access C libraries. I also omitted the test for `2` and `3`, since you can just add those manually once you've finished with the loop.

I can pretty much guarantee that this will have bugs because I don't have your test data and a comprehension this big (for me, anyway) would really need testing. It's technically a one-liner, but I've tried to split it up for readability. Hopefully, though, it at least gives you some ideas.

```
biglist = [ # this will be a list of booleans
    not int(line)%2 or # the number is not even
    not int(line)%3 or # not divisible by 3
    (
        not int(line)%i or # not divisible by each item in the range() object
        not int(line)%(i+2) for i in # nor by 2 greater than each item
            # and only go through the range() object while it's still prime
            itertools.takewhile(lambda x: not int(line)%x or not int(line)%(x+2),
        range(5, int(pow(int(line), 0.5))+1, 6)) # pow(x, 0.5) uses a built-in instead of an imported module
    )
for line in  sys.stdin) if line.lstrip('-+').isdigit() # going through each item in sys.stdin
# as long as long as it's a digit. if you only expect positive numbers, you can omit ".lstrip('-+')".
]

total_of_primes = len(biglist) + 2 # manually add 2 and 3 instead of testing it
```

If you can't get the execution time down far enough, you might consider moving to a lower-level (slower to write, faster to run) language, like C.

Comment: "Comprehensions are faster than native Python code, because they access C libraries" - they don't do that to any greater degree than an equivalent loop. I believe there are some bytecode optimizations specific to comprehensions and genexps that can't be applied to equivalent loops, but nothing that provides a really massive speedup.

Comment: Darn. Well, like I said, I hope something in there is useful.

Comment: Well, I can't add 2 and 3 because what I'm reading in is a .txt file of random numbers. And I need to test each number to see if it's prime. That's why I am checking if it is 2 or 3.

Comment: Maybe you could add `int(line) in (2,3) or` before checking `not int(line)%2`? Then if it's `2` or `3` it'll immediately mark it as prime without checking the other conditions (short-circuiting).